# Regex to match text between specified delimiters? (I just can't get it myself)

Tags: regex

I've been googling & trying to get this myself but can't quite get it...

QUESTION: What regular expression could be used to select text BETWEEN (but not including) the delimiter text.   So as an example:

```
Start Marker=ABC
Stop Marker=XYZ

---input---
This is the first line
And ABCfirst matched hereXYZ
and then
again ABCsecond matchXYZ
asdf
------------

---expected matches-----
[1] first matched here
[2] second match
------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: One quick comment for anyone reading this -- if you're looking at this question because you want to use regular expressions for XML parsing, don't. It's something I see folks trying to do in #bash frequently, and it's a Very Bad Idea -- XML parsing is surprisingly difficult to get right, and any attempt to capture the intricacies of the syntax in a regular expression is bound to fail. Use a library or tool built for the purpose -- if, like the folks asking in #bash, you want something you can use from a shell script, see XMLStarlet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard or extended regex syntax can't do that, but what it *can* do is create match groups which you can then select. For instance:

```
ABC(.*)XYZ
```

will store anything between `ABC` and `XYZ` as `\1` (otherwise known as group 1).

If you're using PCREs (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), lookahead and lookbehind assertions are also available -- but groups are the more portable and better-performing solution. Also, if you're using PCREs, you should use `*?` to ensure that the match is non-greedy and will terminate at the first opportunity.

You can test this yourself in a Python interpreter (the Python regex syntax is PCRE-derived):

```
>>> import re
>>> input_str = '''
... This is the first line
... And ABC first matched hereXYZ
... and then
... again ABCsecond matchXYZ
... asdf
... '''
>>> re.findall('ABC(.*?)XYZ', input_str)
[' first matched here', 'second match']
```

Comment: would the \1 group contain "first matched here" and "second match", or everything between first ABC till last XYZ?

Comment: @kender - To have only one match, two things would need to be true: The multiline flag would need to be set, and the asterisk would need to be greedy. Otherwise, we have two separate matches, each of which has its own groups.

Comment: I'm actually using C#, so is the idea I might be able to get at the groups (e.g. \1 group) in C#?

Comment: @Greg - Absolutely; if you have a Match m, see m.Groups.

Comment: got it thanks:

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
                Console.Out.WriteLine(groups[1]);
            }

Comment: It isn't the Multiline flag that would need to be set, it's RegexOptions.Singleline (in Python it would be re.DOTALL or re.S).

Answer (score 3):

/ABC(.*?)XYZ/

By default, regular expression matches are greedy. The '?' after the . wildcard character, denotes a minimal match, so that the first match is this:

```
first matched here
```

...instead of this:

```
first matched hereXYZ
and then
again ABCsecond match
```

Comment: @Sonam - Depends on the regex syntax in use -- remember, we have basic, extended, and Perl-Compatible; only the last of those recognizes the question mark as modifying greedy behavior.

Comment: .? would match zero or one charachter -- you also need * or +

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, of course it should be .*? or .+?...  my regex-fu is weak, and its PCRE :)

Answer (score 0):

You want the non-greedy match, `.*?`

```
while( $string =~ /ABC(.*?)XYZ/gm ) {
  $match = $1;
}
```

Comment: (this perl.. There is a reason so many languages use perl style regex...). ;-)